# Has the manuscript writer at the start of Volume 7 appeared before?

Tags: phantom-tales-of-the-night

At the start of the Thirtieth Enigma in Volume 7 of the manga Phantom Tales of the Night, owner talks to a manuscript writer who is said to have been to the inn multiple times before. He looks a bit like Karibara, the guest that fell in love with Owner, but I don't think its the same person.

Is the manuscript writer that owner talks to in Volume 7 someone I should recognize from earlier in the story?

[image: start of 30th enigma showing owner and a blonde guest]